# android have error "Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference".featFCM

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences, firebase-cloud-messaging, nullreferenceexception

i have problem
i want control FCM sound for button boolean
my boolean is save shared preferences
I did init but why this error

[image: my error image]

this is my button boolean save source

```
 private static SharedPreferences mPrefs;
        private static SharedPreferences.Editor mPrefsEditor;
        private static final String noti = "pref_key_noti_onoff";
     public static void initPrefs(Context context) {
            if( mPrefs == null){
                mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", 0);
                mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
             }
        }
        public static boolean getSettingnoti() {
            return mPrefs.getBoolean(noti,true);
        }
  public static void setSettingnoti(boolean onoff) {
        mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
        mPrefsEditor.putBoolean(noti,onoff);
        mPrefsEditor.commit();

    }
```

this is my fcm received source

```
 public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            if (DataSaver.getSettingnoti()){}
            else{
                mPrefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                mPrefsEditor.putBoolean(noti,true);
                mPrefsEditor.commit();
            }

            if (DataSaver.getSettingnoti() == false) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: ");
            } else {
                Integer.parseInt(DataSaver.getSettingsttime());
                Integer.parseInt(DataSaver.getSettingedtime());

                Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived:" + Integer.parseInt(DataSaver.getSettingsttime()) + Integer.parseInt(DataSaver.getSettingedtime()));

                sendPushNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
                set_alarm_badge();
            }
        }
```

Comment: opps not sound i dont want recived fcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify this code and perform null check on object before using it.

```
public static boolean getSettingnoti() {
            if(mPrefs != null)
                return mPrefs.getBoolean(noti,true);
            /* put some log here */
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: can you please upvote my answer if it solves your problem.